# Linux Kernel module Atomic mode

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, atomic

I am developing linux kernel module to perform read/write operations.
It reads an input file and write the content to an output file.
I have to introduce atomic mode to my code.
I wanted to know if there is a way to revert changes from a written file in case of partial write for atomic mode.

I want to delete all content I have written to an output file in case my programs gives an error.

Please reply.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. A write (e.g. of a 2Gb buffer) can take an unbounded (i.e. large) amount of time. And you don't want to make that atomic in the kernel.

Comment: I want to do it for small files (less than 1 mb).

Comment: Why do you believe that you need to code a kernel module for that purpose???

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve but I'll bet that doing it in the kernel side is definitely the wrong way about it.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to delete all content I have written to an output file in case my programs gives an error.

I would avoid developing a kernel module for that purpose.

You can simply do that in the shell or in the application code: [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) into some temporary file, then [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) the file on success or [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) it on failure. Or you could do that in some shell script (e.g. redirecting stdout to a temporary file, then `mv` or `rm` it). You need to understand more what [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) are.

If you insist on having something kernel related, consider [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)

NB: kernel code is usually not expected to write files. Only application code are writing files, using some [filesystem](http://www.science.unitn.it/~fiorella/guidelinux/tlk/node94.html) code in the kernel.

PS: You might be perhaps interested by [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html).